# Drupal diffentent reasult for en-us and en-ca

Tags: drupal

I got a work on a drupal site that build by others. This site goes to siteurl/en-ca when login from Canada and goes to siteurl/en-us when login from usa.
How can retrieve only /en-ca reasult when searching in google from canada
How can retrieve only /en-us reasult when searching in google from USA

Answer (score 0):

you my friend might need this: https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip_redirect

> GeoIP Redirect uses the GeoIP API to redirect a user from your site to a different one based on their country of origin. The primary use-case is that you have 2 different markets and want to ensure users are accessing the correct form of that material. Here is a typical workflow for this module:

dont forget to thumbs up! :)

Comment: I want the google search result page to show the result of example.com/n-ca  only  when the user browse from canada,

Comment: it requires https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip amd also asking to enable CURL and install libraries through composer.

Comment: Actually I don't want that. My output will be a google search page which shows on x country sites  link when its searching from X and Y country  sites link when searching from Y country